# The translation failed because the online translation service was unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, machine-translation

I was trying to translate a page, but this error message appear

The translation failed because the online translation service was unavailable. Please resubmit this file for translation. If the file fails again with this error message, contact your system administrator.

I downloaded all the certificates, but still same error

this are the certificates 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After installing all the certificates, you must do the following:

- Restart `Machine Translation Service` in Central Administration.
- Restart `IIS`.

Comment: did that already